# Provide APN settings from outside without Internet (i.e. SMS, QR Code)

Tags: sms, settings, mobile-network, apn, qr-code

I'm looking for a way to provide APN settings to a device that doesn't have an internet connection yet.
It is intended to set up hundreds of devices more quickly by a variety of users across the country. They have sim cards for each device, but we need to change the APN settings for them to work. Testing has shown that our customers/users have the most trouble with this step.

Is it possible to provide APN settings via QR-Code or SMS?

You can prompt a user to go to WIFI settings etc. this way, but can you provide a configuration, too?

It of course doesn't have to be 'hidden', but we want to avoid people typing off these addresses, the easier we can make the set up process of their devices, the better.

Comment: In my knowledge, only carriers can do such things over the air. You should ask your customers to contact their respective carriers to get the appropriate configurations or you can send them instructions by sms depending on which carrier they are.

Comment: APN settings typically come via SMS by the carrier or are built into the SIM card.